# Date format in javascript with time 00:00:00

Tags: javascript

How to get Date Format as

```
 Fri Dec 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

**Todays** date with time 00:00:00 in `javascript` ?
Any help appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var myDate = new Date(); 
    myDate.setHours(0,0,0);

    alert(myDate);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nrud7j8v/2

about javascript setHours() method  [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setHours...](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setHours.asp)